# Best way in SQL to store Name of Column along with the value of a particular row dynamically within a Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to retrieve the name and value of each column in a SQL table for a particular record, and store them as a separate entry in a different table using a stored procedure. I have tried using an INSERT EXEC statement within a loop, but I get an error saying that it cannot be nested within a stored procedure. How can I achieve this dynamic column name/value pairing in MS SQL Server?

For example, given the following table:

| Id | Name | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Jane' | 'USA' |
| 2 | 'Tyrion' | 'UK' |

I want to retrieve the data for a specific Id (e.g. 1) and store the column name and value as separate entries in a different table like this:

| Column Name | Column Value |
| --- | --- |
| Id | 1 |
| Name | 'Jane' |
| Place | 'USA' |

Please suggest a solution or workaround.

Comment: You need to unpivot your data. Honestly, this type of work is best done in the application layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: If your column names are fixed than why not just use union all like `SELECT 'Id' AS [Column Name],Id AS [Column Value] FROM YourTable WHERE Id=1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Name' AS [Column Name],Name AS [Column Value] FROM YourTable WHERE Id=1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Place' AS [Column Name],Place AS [Column Value] FROM YourTable WHERE Id=1`

Comment: @ThomA I agree, but I need this within a Stored Procedure, hence cannot do it in application layer. I'll see if unpivot helps.

Comment: That's unlikely to be as performant as an unpivot, @Sandeep . Such a solution would result in multiple seeks (assuming a valid index) on the table, rather than a single one.

Comment: *"I need this within a Stored Procedure"* Why do you "need" it in an procedure?

Comment: In a stored procedure? Simply fetch the row, and then do what you need with the values you've got. (Similar as you would have done in the application layer.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that will dynamically UNPIVOT virtually any table, view or query WITHOUT enumerating columns or using Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select A.[Id]
      ,Item  = B.[Key]
      ,Value = B.[Value]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] not in ('Id','Other','Columns','ToExclude')
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
Id  Item    Value
1   Name    Jane
1   Place   USA
2   Name    Tyrion
2   Place   UK
```

**UPDATE ... XML Version**

```
Select A.Id
      ,C.Item
      ,C.Value
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
               Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                     ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                From  xmlData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not in  ('Id')
             ) C
```

Comment: `OPENJSON` isn't supported in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: maybe he doesn't use it though and just selected some random version